# call C# function from HTML link

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET C# website.
On this website will be a GridView with some data in it,
and you should be able to export this data (excel, whatever).

For the export i will use the code on this [website](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx).

When someone clicks the export link a popup will fire up like this:

[image]

The popup is made with [avgrund](http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/) and the "buttons" are HTML links.

```
$(function () {
        $('#exportlaces').avgrund({
            height: 80,
            width: 380,
            holderClass: 'container',
            showClose: true,
            showCloseText: 'x',
            closeByEscape: true,
            onBlurContainer: '#main-wrapper',
            template: '<div id="exportpopuptop"></div>' +
            '<div id="exportpopup">' +
            '<ul>' +
            '<li><a href="#">Excel</a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</div>'
     });
});
```

I need now to fire up some C# code with the HTML links for the export. But how?

I tried something like this:

```
<a runat="server" OnServerClick="myFunction_Click">Excel</a>
```

But this doesn't work since I'm outside of the form tag.
And only one form tag is allowed with runat="server".

I also tried to add ASP.NET buttons to the popup, but this didn't work either.

Is there a way to fire up a javascript function which will fire up C# ?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

The code looks now like this

```
$(function () {
    $('#exportlaces').avgrund({
        height: 80,
        width: 380,
        holderClass: 'container',
        showClose: true,
        showCloseText: 'x',
        closeByEscape: true,
        onBlurContainer: '#main-wrapper',
        template: '<div id="exportpopuptop"></div>' +
        '<div id="exportpopup">' +
        '<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"> Excel</asp:LinkButton>' +
        '</div>'
    }).appendTo("#form1");
});
```

And the C# code behind like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace LACE
{
  public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your server side code goes here...
    }

  }
}
```

And I get the following error message:

> **Compiler Error Message**: CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'LinkButton1_Click' and no extension method
>   'LinkButton1_Click' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Comment: "Is there a way to fire up a javascript function which will fire up C# ?" No, not in the way you seem to be thinking.  You can't execute a C# function on the user's PC from a link in a web browser.  The C# function must be part of your ASP.NET site, run on the server, and if your function returns a result to the user, it must do so via the HTTP response.  That being said, there are two ways to accomplish this: (continued in next comment).

Comment: 1) Have the button submit your entire form to make the HTTP request, and your whole page will refresh, or 2) Have the button perform an AJAX HTTP request, and then have your javascript accept the response and update a small part of your page without refreshing the rest of it.  It looks like there are answers below that cover both methods.

Comment: But then he doesn't need to do that. If he puts a server side Link in the pop up and gets the popup to be inside the <form> tag, it'll automatically fire the server side event.

Comment: @ElSyr With reference to your updated question, it won't work because the server control has to be present on the when the controls of the page are being initialized.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to call a javascript function on the html button click and in that javascript function , you can call the server side function using ASP.Net AJAX ScriptManager.

The first thing you need to do is add a ASP.Net AJAX ScriptManager to the page and set itsEnablePageMethods property to true as shown below:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Now you can call the page method (C#) methods as below from your javascript function :

```
PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").value,   
  OnSuccess);
```

where the server side method is as follows:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The current time is: "
    + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

You can call this javascript function from your html control.

[For detail and implementation you can refer to this link.](http://www.counsellingbyabhi.com/2013/08/callingserversidesmethodsfromjs.html)

Answer (score 1):

You said the whole div is being put outside the form tag, so to get it inside the  tag use -

http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

```
$(function () {
        $('#exportlaces').avgrund({
            height: 80,
            width: 380,
            holderClass: 'container',
            showClose: true,
            showCloseText: 'x',
            closeByEscape: true,
            onBlurContainer: '#main-wrapper',
            template: '<div id="exportpopuptop"></div>' +
            '<div id="exportpopup">' +
            '<ul>' +
            '<li><a href="#">Excel</a></li>' +
            '<li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</div>'
     }).appendTo("#form1"); // any jquery selector for the form will work
});
```

Also change your server side control to something like this...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="" runat="server" OnClick=""></asp:LinkButton>
```

Remember to specify the ID. You can style it the way you want using CSS class. That would be the simple way out, otherwise if you want to call a C# function from JavaScript, you'll have to use [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

This is a [basic tutorial](http://thecurlybraces.com/) I wrote for something making a jQuery ajax call, you can modify it to suit your needs.

Let me know if you have any further doubts.

EDIT #1 -

You added this -

`<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"> Excel</asp:LinkButton>`

Now create the following function in the code behind file...

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your server side code goes here...
    }
```

EDIT #2- 
With reference to your updated question, It won't work because the server control has to be present on the when the controls of the page are being initialized.

I have an idea though that might work,

Set this as your jQuery function -

```
$(function () {
    $('#exportlaces').avgrund({
        height: 80,
        width: 380,
        holderClass: 'container',
        showClose: true,
        showCloseText: 'x',
        closeByEscape: true,
        onBlurContainer: '#main-wrapper',
        template: '<div id="exportpopuptop"></div>' +
        '<div id="exportpopup">' +        
        '</div>'
    }).appendTo("#form1");

    // Store a reference to the link and then remove the button from the page first.
    var lnkBtn = $("#<%=LinkButton1.ClientID%>");
    $(lnkBtn).remove();
    // Now add it to the 'exportpopup' div
    $("#exportpopup").append(lnkBtn);

});
```

Now in your aspx page define the control -

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"> Excel</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Hi. I added `}).appendTo("form1");` and I changed the HTML links to the asp linkbutton like this: 
`'<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Excel</asp:LinkButton>' +`
But then I am getting:
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'LinkButton1_Click' and no extension method 'LinkButton1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is that function `LinkButton1_Click` present in your code behind file? That's a server side function. You have to create in your .cs file.

@ElSyr - Also I assume that `form1` is the id for the form, if so you should be using `}).appendTo("#form1");`

Comment: oh. I added the # in front of the form. And my code looks like this:
`public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }`
But something is not working :/

Comment: @ElSyr Check my updated code. Is the page refreshing when you hit the link button

Comment: ok. I added the linkbutton to the page, but I still get the same compiler error.

Comment: Please put the code of the .aspx page and the .cs page in your question. The whole thing.

Comment: I could send it to you personally, because I don't want to poste the whole website.

Comment: @ElSyr, If you are still stuck on this, do sent it to me then, I'll get it working, and send it back.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I will find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

//have a look at the following working example, i just used button instead of Link, you can use link also just define onclick for it.

// Code behind method declared static

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSquare(String value)
{
  return value;
}
```

your button whose click this has to be done

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Chnageurl" onclick="ajaxcall()" />
```

script for this

```
<script type="text/jscript">

function ajaxcall(e) {

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetSquare",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ value: "somevalue" }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (value) {
        alert(value.d);
    },
   error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
 });
};
```